# Как пользоваться делегатами?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичёк в этом деле, пытаюсь изучить и научиться пользоваться делегатами. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Разный возвращаемый тип

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Смотрите.

Делегат — это просто такой тип, что в переменные этого типа вы можете записывать не числа и объекты, а функции*, и вызывать их потом. Вот собственно и всё, что вам нужно знать для начала.

Чтобы объявить такую переменную, компилятор должен знать какого типа аргументы будут у этой функции, и какого типа возвращаемое значение. Это ему нужно, чтобы он знал, как правильно вызывать функцию по этой переменной, и какого типа будет результат. Когда вы объявляете делегат, вы именно эту информацию и даёте:

```
delegate int mydel(int x, int y);
  ^      \_____________________/
  |                   |
объявляется делегат   |
                      |
                 а это показывает, какие функции использовать с этим делегатом
                 только вместо имени функции название делегата
```

У вас в коде функция возвращает значение, поэтому в определении делегата тоже должно быть возвращаемое значение.

Вы можете исправить код так:

```
class Program
{
    delegate int mydel(int x, int y); // поменяли возвращаемое значение на int

    static int sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mydel g = sum; // здесь можно без new, просто присвоить. так проще, правда?
        int result = g(10, 5);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + result);
    }
}
```

---

*(*Примечание для знатоков.*) Да, это упрощение. На самом деле у нас multicast delegate, так что их можно складывать и вызывать через `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`. И да, делегат является объектом. Я упрощаю картину для понятности.

Answer (score 6):

Вы объявили возвращаемый тип делегата void, а передаете метод с возвращаемым значением int. Задайте возвращаемое значение делегата на int. 
Есть еще подозрение что не будет работать метод с модификатором static. Сделайте что я сказал, запустите и отпишитесь.

Comment: почему бы ему не работать со статическими функциями?

Comment: @Qutrix просто предположил, давно не использовал c# :)